# Fastest way to encode and decode data in scala

Tags: scala, csv, data-structures, encoding, hashmap

I have the following csv file:

```
Name    Age City    Start   Stop    Point
Mike    29  Fuji    10      30      5
Mike    29  Fuji    0       10      7
Susan   26  Fuji    77      1000    9
```

I'm trying to access the Point, given name, age, city and range

Example given:

```
Mike, 29, Fuji, 15 will yield 5
Mike, 29, Fuji, 5 will yield 7
Susan, 26, Fuji, 990 will yield 9
Susan, 26, Fuji, 1500 will yield 0 since there's no match
```

I read the csv and tried to construct a Scala Map[String, Map[Int, Map[String, Map[Int, Int]]]] but that is not very scalable given I have few thousand records. The start and stop ranges are disjoint and have to relation with other rows.

How can I encode and decode this data efficiently without using a SQL database or a KeyValue store? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Are the intervals disjoint between all the records?

Comment: @Laurent yes, they are disjoint between all records

Comment: @Amanda, I don't know Scala enough for providing an answer but from a data structure point of view, you could use an interval tree for efficient lookup based on intervals (although a few thousand records in memory is not a lot). An implementation is, for instance, the [TreeRangeMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeRangeMap.html) class from the Guava library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a naive version using case classes for the key (`Person`) and the ranges (`RangeAndPoint`) - there are some missing details in the post (e.g. are ranges inclusive/exclusive? Are they disjoint? What should be the result of no matching range is found? If more than one is found?) - but these can be fixed in the answer:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, city: String)

case class RangeAndPoint(start: Int, end: Int, point: Int) {
  def inRange(value: Int): Boolean = value < end && value >= start
}

// Let's assume CSV was read into such a format - I'll hard-code it here for the example:
val persons: Map[Person, List[RangeAndPoint]] = Map(
  Person("Mike", 29, "Fuji") -> List(RangeAndPoint(10, 30, 5), RangeAndPoint(0, 10, 7)),
  Person("Susan", 26, "Fuji") -> List(RangeAndPoint(77, 1000, 9))
)

// returns the expected result or None if no match found:
def getPoint(name: String, age: Int, city: String, value: Int): Option[Int] = {
  persons
    .get(Person(name, age, city))
    .flatMap(_.find(_.inRange(value)))
    .map(_.point)
}

println(getPoint("Mike", 29, "Fuji", 15))   // Some(5)
println(getPoint("Mike", 29, "Fuji", 5))    // Some(7)
println(getPoint("Susan", 26, "Fuji", 990)) // Some(9)
```

Comment: Thanks Tzach, very interesting approach.

Comment: does it require a .flatMap there? I guess just .find will work.

Comment: I can't see a way around `flatMap` nor a reason to remove it - the result of `persons.get(...)` is an `Option[List[...]]`, not the list itself, so you want to map the list (if it exists) into an `Optional[RangeAndPoint]` and then `flatten` the resulting `Option[Option[RangeAndPoint]]` into the desired `Option[RangeAndPoint]`.